# PHP image upload database

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

I have a problem with my image uploader. I get the message that my file has been uploaded  ad it does upload to the folder but it doesn't upload the info into my database. I always get 2 errors.

> Error 1:Notice: Undefined index: pachal_gip_UserID in /Users/pachalrobberecht/6 MUL 2013-2014/GIP/Internet Technieken/media.php on line 162
>
> Error2: Warning: mysqli_prepare() [function.mysqli-prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Users/pachalrobberecht/6 MUL 2013-2014/GIP/Internet Technieken/media.php on line 169
>   Media

```php
if (!empty($_POST['upload'])){
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
      && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
      && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } else {
            $newfile = 'Tekening_' . $_SESSION['pachal_gip_Username1'];
            echo "<p>Je tekening is geupload.</p>";
            $succes++;
        }

        if (file_exists("images/tekeningen/" . $newfile)) {
            echo 'Je hebt reeds deelgenomen';
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "images/tekeningen/" . $newfile . '.' . $extension);
            $afbeeld = 'images/tekeningen/' . $newfile . '.' . $extension;

            //Start controle velden
            $afbeelding = $afbeeld;
            $userID = $_SESSION['pachal_gip_UserID'];

            if (!empty($afbeelding)) {
                $qryTekeningen = "INSERT INTO tblTekeningen (TekeningID, Tekening, UserID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconn,  $qryTekeningen)) {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isi", $id, $afbeelding, $userID);
                    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                        $feedback = '<p>The  drawing has been added.</p>';
                        $feedback .='<p><a href="wedstrijd.php">Klik hier</a> om terug te gaan</p>';
                        $succes = 1;
                    } else {
                        $feedback = '<p>Het toevoegen van je Tekening is mislukt ' . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) . '<p>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }     
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add echo $qryTekeningen  after the query statement and paste the output so that we will get a clearer idea about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 is saying that there's no `pachal_gip_UserID` index in the `$_SESSION` array. Could this be a typo? Perhaps it's meant to be `pachal_gip_UserId`, or perhaps it's just not been set at all.

Issue 2 is possibly because the mysqli connection wasn't initialized correctly, we may need to see where you are setting up the connection.

Comment: Issue 1 isn't related to a typo. I did double check it to make sure.


Issue 2: Normally the it schould connect because i use the same connection file for all my other pages and it works on those other pages. Here is the code

    <?php
 define("SERVERNAME", "localhost");
 define("USERNAME", "pachal_gip");
 define("PASSWORD", "Gip_123");
 define("DATABASE", "pachal_gip");

 $dbconn = mysqli_connect(SERVERNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't set session variable

```
   $_SESSION['pachal_gip_UserID'];
```

before or forgoten to put

```
   session_start();
```

in the beginning.